# Bottom and top plot labels facet ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

**Data structure:** Assume you have 2 groups of variables with 3 sublevels each. Let's name them A1, A2, A3 (A-group), B1, B2, B3 (B-group). All integer-type ranging 5-25. Each variable has description in form of 'A1Lower / A1Upper' and so on.

**Dataset & Packages:** You can generate dataset with the code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# We will need subscales later
subscales <- paste0(rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 3), 1:3)
# Dataset
data <- replicate(6, sample(5:25, 500, replace = T)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  setNames(subscales)
```

I've created a `facet_wrap` of `geom_violion` with `geom_boxplot()` and labels (custom labeller) based on description, with the code below:

```
subscales_labeller <- paste0(subscales, 'Lower / ', subscales, 'Upper') %>%
  setNames(subscales) %>% #as a named vector
  as_labeller() #as a ggplot2 labeller

data %>%
  gather(subscale, value, factor_key = T) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = '', y = value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) +
  facet_wrap(~subscale, ncol = 3, labeller = subscales_labeller) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = '', y = '')
```

**Goal:** The problem is that the whole label comes on top. I want the Upper description above the violin plot and Lower description below. So far I managed to set x scale as character with the Lower description and labeller with just Upper desciption. It is not perfect as it complicates many things for me (for example I would like to use `color = Sex` aesthetic) that is why I would prefer to set something like bottom and top labels at once. Not to mention a side lebels with 'A group' and 'B group' desciptions (this would be like heaven but not a must for this post)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but wouldn't using Upper / Lower labels added with `geom_text()` solve the issue? I don't see why you would need the facet labels for this.

Comment: I didn't consider using `geom_text()`, could you show me how would you do it? You can provide code for just one plot that will work with facet because I still need all these plots in one `facet_wrap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is posted as a reponse to OP's comment for a version of the facetted plot that uses `geom_text()` to label upper/lower bounds.

I've made two versions, one static code and one adaptive one. I've also taken the liberty to switch to `facet_grid()` to accommodate the side labels that OP expressed some interest in. Below is the static version, assume `data` comes from the code you posted:

```
df <- data %>% gather(subscale, value, factor_key = T) %>%
  mutate(letter = paste("Group", substr(subscale, 1, 1)),
         number = substr(subscale, 2, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(x = '', y = value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(value = c(max(df$value), min(df$value)),
                              label = c("Upper", "Lower")),
            aes(label = label),
            nudge_y = c(1, -1)) +
  facet_grid(letter ~ number) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

In this case, "Upper" and "Lower" will always be be one y-axis unit above/below the extremes of the entire data. You might want to adjust the `nudge_y` to be appropriate for your size of the plot.

The following piece of code will place the labels adaptively with respect to the group's maximum/minimum. To illustrate this, I've thrown out some observations to show that the labels are placed correctly.

```
df <- df[!(df$subscale == "A2" & df$value > 15),]

ggplot(df, aes(x = '', y = value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = "Upper"), stat = "summary", fun.y = "max", 
            position = position_nudge(y = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = "Lower"), stat = "summary", fun.y = "min", 
            position = position_nudge(y = -1)) +
  facet_grid(letter ~ number) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

EDIT: with custom labels per facet, sex and age:

```
labs <- expand.grid(value = range(df$value),
                    letter = unique(df$letter),
                    number = unique(df$number))
labs$label <- c("Sweet", "Sour", "Introvert", "Extrovert",
                "Idiot", "Genius", "Dark", "Light",
                "Small", "Big", "Tom-eh-to", "Tom-ah-to")

df$sex <- sample(c("F", "M"), size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$age <- sample(c("<20", "20-30", ">30"), size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(x = sex, y = value)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = age)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = age), width = 0.1,
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_text(data = labs,
            aes(x = 1.5, label = label),
            nudge_y = c(-1, 1)) +
  facet_grid(letter ~ number) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: First - thank you for the example with 2 options and the `facet_grid` allowing group description. I will stick with the first one as lower and upper description correspond to the edge-values of 5 and 25 (psychological dichotomous scales). **Still** The "Lower" and "Upper" are not descriptions shared by all plots - in fact top left plot should have "A1Lower" and "A1Upper" then next to it "A2Lower" and "A2Upper" and so on. In fact, it's more like "Skeptic" and "Trustful" for A1, "Realism" and "Fantasize" for B1 and so on.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I've added an example for that. If the labels are the same for the number (i.e. labels for B1 are same as A1), you can leave out the `number = ...` from the `expand.grid()` and label accordingly.

Comment: Great, it works now :) Next step would be to split plots by 1 or 2 variables like `x = Sex` and `color=Age` inside but then I get error because I want the label in the middle (not for each Sex or Age). Do you know how to add text in this situation?

Comment: Discrete label get internally converted to a continuous range, so for two x axis groups, `x` of labels should be 1.5 (first group is at 1, second at 2). I've updated the example to include sex and age as variables, but I'm not exactly sure how to calculate the `position_dodge()` number, it was trial and error to get this to fit. Also might want to order the age labels to be appropriate to your data.

Comment: Thank you once again. I got the right code, just messed up my factor levels and it didn't work. Anyways thank you for providing this code and your whole help in this post :)